# windows 10 GetLastWin32Error() ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c#

Hello i have visual studio 2017 free version 
and i try make program use movewindow the problem is when i use it i have error nr 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and thats why movewindow dont work.

i open vs2017 with adminstration permision adn its dosent work to.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {




        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,null,"Kalkulator");


        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {


            diagnoza.Text = "znalazl" + "\r\n";


            MoveWindow(hWnd,0,0,100,100,true);
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            diagnoza.Text += "błąd nr : " + error;
        }

        else { diagnoza.Text = "nie znalazl" + "\r\n" ;
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            diagnoza.Text += "błąd nr : " + error;
        }
    }


    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

   [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);



}
```

Comment: As an experiment: What happens if you run your program as an administrator?

Comment: There are *two* GetLastWin32Error() calls in this snippet.  Which one is it?  The first one is plain wrong, you must only ever obtain an error code if the api function failed.  In other words, when MoveWindow() returns *false*.  Failure to do this correctly produces a random number.  The second one is not wrong that same way, seeing FindWindowEx fail is certainly not unusual.  Especially so on Win10, the calculator app is no longer a traditional Windows desktop program.  Boilerplate advice is to use UI automation, System.Windows.Automation namespace in .NET